# Is there a chance for a laptop with a static IP to get connected to a random Wifi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp, wifi-configuration, dhcp-server

Is there a chance for a laptop with a static IP to get connected to a random Wifi network? For example: a laptop is configured with a static IP address of 192.168.1.5 and attempts to connect to a random Wifi network.

I ask from a security point of view. Lets say that an intruder broke the Wifi password. Is there even a slight chance for him to connect with a static IP (assuming that IP is not used at the moment)?

Comment: @John, I ask from a a security point of view.

Comment: Why don't you try it, (you'll find that it is possible) - I mean, I have a few wifi connected devices that have a static IP and they work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I ask from a security point of view. Lets say that an intruder broke the Wifi password. Is there even a slight chance for him to connect with a static IP (assuming that IP is not used at the moment)?

Very high, considering how many home routers use the exact same 192.168.1.0/24 network prefix. (If the attacker knows what ISP is most popular in their location, they can make use of the fact that ISP-issued routers tend to use the exact same configuration.)

But an attacker who is actively interested in using the network doesn't need to rely on chance; once physically in the network, they can *very* quickly find out what network prefixes and what gateway addresses are being used, even if you change them to something unusual and if you disable DHCP and everything. It's easier than breaking the Wi-Fi password.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  If the WiFi on the laptop is configured to access a specific network SSID and another WiFi network uses the same SSID and password, then it will attempt to connect.  If the new WiFi allows for static IPs and it is available, it is possible for the laptop to connect.

Many people do this when they replace an old router with a new one.  They just set everything the same on the new router and everything connecting to the old one, will connect to the new one.