# Is it possible to force the use of DHCP on Wireless connections? (i.e. not on Wired ones)

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp, dhcp-server

I have an Asus router AC87U. Is it possible to block wireless connection for devices that are configured with a static IP while still allowing LAN connections for devices that are also configured with a static IP?

I.e. for Wireless connections only DHCP while for Wireless connections both DHCP and static IP.

I ask from the point of view of security. I want to set a single static IP for the router Web UI and to keep that IP only to a Wired connection computer. In a way that a Wireless connected device will have no chance to connect with that IP: Since the DHCP will never provide it (its pool start is above that IP) and an attempt to a Wireless connect using a static IP will be rejected.

Comment: so based on your last question, the static IP bit isn't particularly important to your overall safety. an attacker with an address your dhcp server provided is (in most circumstances) as dangerous as an attacker with a static IP. having a static IP doesn't really help them do anything, unless they plan to masquerade as a very trusted host on your network. for most people that wouldn't make them more vulnerable than having an attacker with a DHCP address. also you can't really force the use of DHCP, unless you are on an enterprise environment.

Comment: @FrankThomas, I updated my question to make clear my intention.

Comment: based on your updates, we'll need to see a proposed network diagram. what you are asking about is possible, if you have the right network equipment connected and configured the right way, but there are numerous options out there, so we need to know what you are thinking about. the best bet is probably two networks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a chance for a laptop with a static IP to get connected to a random Wifi network?](https://superuser.com/questions/1771255/is-there-a-chance-for-a-laptop-with-a-static-ip-to-get-connected-to-a-random-wif)

Comment: You have two questions open that are very close to the same. Please delete one of them. Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me like you may want to look into 802.1x

Comment: @FrankThomas, can you elaborate on: "you can't really force the use of DHCP, unless you are on an enterprise environment."?

Comment: the choice to use DHCP provided vs a statically assigned address exists only on the client. the network itself does not care one bit. in enterprise environments it is possible to secure resources such that clients must comply with rules/policies in order to access them (for instance to access a network share on a domain member server you are generally required to have the client configured as a member of that domain) but that all happens at the services layer, not at the network layer. the network doesn't care.

Comment: Everything you envision can only ever be solved with professional-grade hardware or at least OpenWrt, be it enforcing DHCP (could be accomplished with relative ease) or simply making Wi-Fi clients unable to access the AP configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I ask from the point of view of security. I want to set a single static IP for the router Web UI and to keep that IP only to a Wired connection computer. In a way that a Wireless connected device will have no chance to connect with that IP: Since the DHCP will never provide it (its pool start is above that IP) and an attempt to a Wireless connect using a static IP will be rejected.

Within a single subnet, it's only possible to enforce this for traffic that goes through the router (i.e. Internet access) – and even then only weakly – but not for traffic that stays within the subnet.

(Devices don't really "connect using an IP", so it is impossible to outright reject Wi-Fi connections based on that; the IP address only comes into play later, when the already-connected device finally starts transmitting data. In other words, the Wi-Fi hardware is unaware of the IP address.)

It is possible to partially enforce your requirement by creating a "static ARP" entry on the router, so that the router will *always* forward packets for that IP to the designated MAC address, instead of using ARP to learn the MAC address dynamically as is the usual mechanism. However:

1. Packets directly between two hosts in the same subnet don't actually go through the router – they're just directly forwarded by Ethernet and Wi-Fi hardware, which is unaware of IP addresses, so you cannot prevent an impostor with that IP address from poking around your LAN – this would only affect Internet access;
2. It is really easy to learn the correct MAC address, and then to change your Wi-Fi interface's MAC address to whatever you want.

In other words, it's kind of garbage as a "security measure". (Again, finding out your network's WPA passphrase was probably the hardest part for the attacker. Once they're in, your weird IP setup is mostly a nuisance.)

If it's supposed to be a security measure, normally this would be solved by creating a completely new IP subnet for "important" computers, on a separate VLAN that would be only assigned to certain Ethernet ports but not to the Wi-Fi access points. That way, only devices physically connected to those Ethernet ports would be in the "trusted" subnet and be able to use any of that subnet's IP addresses.

(It wouldn't be necessary to use static IPs, as each VLAN will have its own DHCP pool anyway, and you could configure static leases on the DHCP server for hosts that you want to get predictable addresses.)